# How to bind a socket.on method to a React functional component

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I am using react functional components to build a collaborative whiteboard with a chat online but I'm getting multiple console.log messages for a single message sent/received.

After some searching I found that the problem is probably because I'm not declaring my socket event listeners inside `componentDidMount()` or the equivalent for functional components.
My code for the whiteboard is something like this:

```
function WhiteBoardArea(props) {
  // Declare useStates here

  socket.on("canvas-change", newCanvasData =>  {
    setCanvasData(newCanvasData)
  });

  //return something
};
```

How can I properly set up this socket.on() method so that it is only run once? (the first time the component is rendered).

Comment: Currently, you are subscribing to the event in every rerender. To do it only on the first render you need to put it in a `useEffect` hook. It will be like this: `useEffect(() => { /* Your Code */ }, [])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `useEffect` hook.

```js
function WhiteBoardArea(props) {
  // Declare useStates here

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("canvas-change", newCanvasData =>  {
      setCanvasData(newCanvasData)
    });
    return () => {
      socket.off("canvas-change");
    }
  }, []);

  //return something
};
```

Passing an empty array as an second argument to `useEffect` is equivalent to `componentDidMount` in React class components, where returned function is for `componentDidUnmount`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! My code is running more smoothly now. But I have a question - why are we turning off the socket connection if the socket.on method only runs once? Why don't we run it once and keep it open?.

Comment: I recommend to unsubscribe from socket events after component destroyed. Or you might face multiple socket event binding problem sooner or later.

Comment: If you have time, see my post: https://dev.to/bravemaster619/how-to-prevent-multiple-socket-connections-and-events-in-react-531d

Comment: Thanks! great post. But when could the component be destroyed? Is it when the user exists the tab?

Comment: Also if we use useEffect without the return or passing the empty array, is that essentially equivalent to not using it at all?

Comment: As I said in my answer, you should use `useEffect` with empty array for `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUnmount`. Not passing at all will cause error, so never consider that option.

Comment: Component would be destroyed when you're leaving that component. However, it's different in react native.